# Oauth-2 authentication extracting the user details expects CustomPrincipal object

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, restful-authentication

I got this code to implement authentication in a Spring boot project. Everything is working fine with the exception of extracting the user who is to be authenticated. I have searched and could not find could not find the solution somewhere else.

```
public class CustomUserAuthenticationConverter implements UserAuthenticationConverter {

    private final String EMAIL = "email";

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> defaultAuthorities;

    public void setDefaultAuthorities(String[] defaultAuthorities) {
        this.defaultAuthorities = AuthorityUtils
                .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(defaultAuthorities));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ?> convertUserAuthentication(Authentication userAuthentication) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        response.put(USERNAME, userAuthentication.getName());

        if (userAuthentication.getAuthorities() != null && !userAuthentication.getAuthorities().isEmpty())
            response.put(AUTHORITIES, AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(userAuthentication.getAuthorities()));

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        if (map.containsKey(USERNAME))
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    new CustomPrincipal(map.get(USERNAME).toString(), map.get(EMAIL).toString()), "N/A",
                    getAuthorities(map));
        return null;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Map<String, ?> map) {
        if (!map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES))
            return defaultAuthorities;

        Object authorities = map.get(AUTHORITIES);

        if (authorities instanceof String)
            return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList((String) authorities);

        if (authorities instanceof Collection)
            return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(
                    StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString((Collection<?>) authorities));

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Authorities must be either a String or a Collection");
    }

}
```

The other parts are working correctly except for this method snippet

```
@Override
        public Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
            if (map.containsKey(USERNAME))
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        new CustomPrincipal(map.get(USERNAME).toString(), map.get(EMAIL).toString()), "N/A",
                        getAuthorities(map));
            return null;
        }
```

I understand that it's expecting a CustomPrincipal object where this Strings are passed as USERNAME, EMAIL. What do I do to pass in the right parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The.problem was that the Lombok library to create constructors failed, so the simple answer is to create them manually.

It works perfectly. The CustomPrincipal class needs to have a constructor that accepts 2 arguments which was implicitly defined but not injected when needed in the class instantiation in another class